# Retrieving Spectral Values at Specific Wavelengths in Landsat Imagery. Is it possible?

Tags: landsat, band

Imagine you are working with Landsat imagery, specifically Landsat 5, and you aim to extract spectral information at 531nm. In this scenario, you would typically choose band 2, as it operates within the range of 520 to 600nm. However, to obtain the precise value for the wavelength 531nm and ensure accurate information, is there a method to retrieve values at specific wavelengths within the designated band range?

I've been contemplating the possibility of using some kind of interpolation, but I'm uncertain about its applicability.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: So far, there are 4 different people trying to close this, for 3 different reasons. It seems they simply do not understand the question! Please, if you don't understand the Q, let someone else deal with it! BTW, the answer is, it is simply not possible to do what you're trying wiht the data given.

Comment: Look into hyperspectral imagery.

Comment: I also think it's not possible, but I'm a newbie. Still, I was thinking the following: Does anyone know how the value for each band is determined? The sensor captures information within a spectrum and provides a corresponding value for each band. How is this value derived? What calculations does the sensor undergo to generate this output? If we understand the process of obtaining the value for each band, could we potentially calculate specific values within the range of a particular band? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

520nm to 631nm is a pretty broad range, and what you're asking is roughly equivalent to asking: "I have total annual rainfall numbers for a country.  How can I get the amount of rain on January 11th?"